# Share internet from Pi running Ubuntu Server 22.04 with USB to Ethernet adapter

Tags: usb, internet, 22.04, ethernet, raspberrypi

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-1014-raspi #16-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 25 09:50:55 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

The wifi signal is not strong where I am sitting. The Pi is connected via ethernet to the router. I want to share the internet connection from this Pi to a nearby laptop (running Ubuntu Desktop 22.04) via a USB to Ethernet Adapter connected to the Pi.

When I attach the adapter (StarTech - USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet NIC Network Adapter) this is what I get in # sudo dmesg

```
[15345.569038] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[15345.595859] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790, bcdDevice= 1.00
[15345.595888] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[15345.595902] usb 2-1: Product: AX88179
[15345.595914] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[15345.595925] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 0000200B80B34
[15345.972329] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth1: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:bb:59:04:b4:00
[15345.979160] usbcore: registered new interface driver ax88179_178a
[15346.018198] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx00200b80b34: renamed from eth1
```

The adapter does not show up in ifconfig.
When I do `# ip a` this is what I get:

```
4: enx00200b80b34: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:bb:59:04:b4:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I have several questions:

1. Why does Ubuntu rename the network interface from eth1? I know I can change it back to eth1 but do I need to?
2. I just want to share the internet connection from the Pi to the laptop. How do I do this? Do I need to mess with netplan? Grub does not exist in Ubuntu for the Raspberry Pi.
3. Do I need to bring UP the network interface?
4. Do I need to mess with `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`?
5. Am I on the right track?

Note:
I changed the mac address above for privacy.

Comment: From your own question  (running Manjaro/Arch) You are not running a supported product to get help on this site.

Comment: I didn't think that would matter. I am asking how to share internet from Ubuntu running on a Pi 4 via a USB to Ethernet adapter. Do you know?

Comment: To an unsupported version so off topic.

Comment: I deleted Manjaro from my laptop and installed Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 on it instead. If anyone would be generous enough to help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: That is not what your question said so please edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. Turns out the linux distro you are running is irrelevant.

First of all I turned off "Predictable network interface names" in my Ubuntu Server 22.04. I didn't really need to but I just wanted to! Because I was running it on a Pi 4 I had to do this by adding `net.ifnames=0` to the begining of the line in `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`

My Ubuntu Pi is connected to the router (via a powerline adapter) using the Pis ethernet adapter. I now connected the USB-To-Ethernet adapter to a spare USB 3 port on the Pi and used a regular ethernet cable to connect it to my laptops ethernet adapter. It did not need to use a crossover cable.

In my case the Pis onboard ethernet was now **eth0** and the adapter was **eth1**.

I then followed the instructions from this [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Internet_sharing).

**Assign a static IPv4 address to eth1:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ip link set up dev eth1 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.123.100/24 dev eth1
```

**Enable Packet forwarding in Ubuntu Pi:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

**Enable NAT (Network Address Translation) in Ubuntu Pi**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

**Give the ethernet interface of the laptop (client) a static IP address and a default route via eth1**
• I was able to do these steps using the "System Settings" of my client linux distro.
• I gave my laptops ethernet interface an ip (192.168.123.15) in the same subnet as the ethernet interface of eth1 on Ubuntu Pi (192.168.123.100).
• Then I told the laptops ethernet interface to use the Ubuntu Pi eth1 interfaces ip address (192.168.123.100) as its default gateway.
• I also assigned DNS servers (8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4 for Google DNS)
• Now the USB-To-Ethernet adapter should light up and you should be able to turn off Wifi on the laptop and continue with network/internet access!
• Note: This will all be lost if you reboot the Pi but you could run a script to configure the iptables rules on boot up.

Comment: install `iptables-persistent` to keep rules persistently if you're on a Debian based distro.  there's probably a similar package on RHEL based distros too.